# NullPointer al ejecutar un PreparedStatement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Estoy intentando generar un `ArrayList` de users desde un `DB`, el caso es que al ejecutar el `PreparedStatement` me devuelve un `NullPointer` y me dice que el objeto conexión es nulo, es algo que no me pasa en otras sentencias que tengo y funcionan.

Dejo el código del `Array` y el código de la clase `Conecta(Objeto Conect)`:

```
      public class Usuario {

      private int id;
      private String nickName;
      private String password;    
      private String Email; 
      private ConectaDB conexion;

      public ArrayList<Usuario> getUsuarios(){
      Connection con = null;
      con = conexion.conecta();
      ArrayList<Usuario> Usuarios = new ArrayList();                    
      PreparedStatement getData = conexion.preparedStatement("SELECT IDUsuario, Nickname, Password, Email FROM usuario");           
      ResultSet data;

      try{            
      data = getData.executeQuery();
      while(data.next()){
        id = data.getInt(1);
        nickName = data.getString(2);
        password = data.getString(3);
        Email = data.getString(4);
      Usuario usser = new Usuario(data.getInt(1), data.getString(2), data.getString(3), data.getString(4));
      Usuarios.add(usser);
      }
       return Usuarios;
  } catch(SQLException e){              
    }  return Usuarios;
}
```

Y aquí está el código de la clase Conecta:

```
  public class ConectaDB {

    public static Connection conecta(){

          Connection conecta=null;

          try{
              Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
              String servidor="jdbc:mysql://xxxxxx:xxxx/bbdd_g1"; //conectamos a nuestra propia maquina
              String usuario="admin_g1";
              String password="a7586";
              //inicializamos objeto conecta, del tipo connection
              conecta = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(servidor, usuario, password);

          }catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
          {
              System.out.println(e.getMessage());
          }
            catch(Exception e) //capturar el resto de exceptions
          {
              System.out.println(e.getMessage());
          }finally{
              return conecta;//como el default de los case, pero se ejecuta si o si
          }

    }    

    public PreparedStatement preparedStatement(String x) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Una pregunta: ¿por qué no usas un simple `Statement` aquí en vez de `PreparedStatement`? ¿Conoces para qué sirve cada uno? ¿Vas a seguir reutilizando la consulta que preparas? Si la respuesta es no, lo más óptimo aquí sería el uso de un `Statement`, ya que tampoco tienes necesidad de proteger el código contra inyección en este caso concreto.

Comment: Es para un proyecto formativo y me exigen que lo utilice, si fuese por mi no me hubiese complicado tanto pero es lo que hay. Gracias por la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque no veamos la declaración del objeto `conexion`, parece que te da NullPointer porque no estás accediendo al objeto con la conexión.

La conexión está en `con` pero el preparedStatement lo sacas de conexion, que es una instancia de ConectaDB.

Editado:
También debería ser prepareStatement (sin d en prepared)

Editado: Puedes usar el siguiente código. He preparado el metodo preparedStatement de conexión para hacer el prepareStatement, pero seguramente deberías elegir una de las siguientes estratégias.
 - Hacer un metodo estático que te prepare la query pasándole la conexión.
 - Hacer ConectaDB un objeto que guarde la conexión y sólo le pases la query.
 - Quitar el metodo prepareStatement de ConectaDB para no liarte con la instancia entre los dos objetos.

```
public class Usuario {

    private int id;
    private String nickName;
    private String password;
    private String Email;
    private ConectaDB conexion;

    public Usuario(int id, String nickName, String password, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nickName = nickName;
        this.password = password;
        Email = email;
    }

    public ArrayList<Usuario> getUsuarios() {
        Connection con = null;
        con = conexion.conecta();
        ArrayList<Usuario> Usuarios = new ArrayList();

        try {
            PreparedStatement getData = con.prepareStatement("SELECT IDUsuario, Nickname, Password, Email FROM usuario");
            ResultSet data;
            data = getData.executeQuery();
            while (data.next()) {
                id = data.getInt(1);
                nickName = data.getString(2);
                password = data.getString(3);
                Email = data.getString(4);
                Usuario usser = new Usuario(data.getInt(1), data.getString(2), data.getString(3), data.getString(4));
                Usuarios.add(usser);
            }
            return Usuarios;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
        return Usuarios;
    }
}
```

y

```
public class ConectaDB {

    public static Connection conecta(){

        Connection conecta=null;

        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String servidor="jdbc:mysql://xxxxxx:xxxx/bbdd_g1"; //conectamos a nuestra propia maquina
            String usuario="admin_g1";
            String password="a7586";
            //inicializamos objeto conecta, del tipo connection
            conecta = DriverManager.getConnection(servidor, usuario, password);

        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(Exception e) //capturar el resto de exceptions
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }finally{
            return conecta;//como el default de los case, pero se ejecuta si o si
        }

    }

    public static PreparedStatement preparedStatement(Connection con ,String sql) throws SQLException {
        return con.prepareStatement(sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: Eso ya lo probé en su momento pero me tira error. El objeto conexion lo tengo declarado como:
private ConectaDB conexion;
Es como he estado haciendolo hasta ahora sin problema ^^

Y lo dicho, al poner con.preparedStatement(...) me indica el IDE que no puede encontrar el método PreparedStatement(String) en la variable con. :/

Comment: Puedes verificar que el objeto `con` es una instancia de `java.sql.Connection`?

Comment: También revisa. Debería ser con.prepareStatement (sin d en prepared)

Comment: Bien, con sí es una instancia de java.sql.Connection luego; al ajustar el prepareStatement ahora ya me lo reconoce de forma correcta con con.prepareStatement. Ahora se me plantea el problema en el que me pide una excepción a parte de  una sentencia SQL. Vaya, literalmente me dice "Unreported SQLException; must be caught or declared"

Comment: Por qué no pruebas a añadir "catch (SQLException e)" a tu estructura try/catch, y luego lo imprimes con "e.printStackTrace()", así tendrás una forma más sencilla de encontrar el error.

Comment: ¡Perfecto! Ahora no tira error y funciona perfectamente, ¡muchas gracias a ambos!

Comment: Me alegro :) Vigila sin embargo esa excepción, que de algún lado saldría!

Comment: Recordad que los comentarios no están hechos para dar la solución. La respuesta debería ser editada para reflejar los cambios que ayudaron al OP, y éste debería marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: El prepareStatement tiene que estar dentro del try - catch que tienes para el SqlException

Comment: Tienes toda la razón tocayo, ahora edito la respuesta.

Comment: Por favor, si la respuesta te sirvió, márcala como aceptada y dale voto útil.

Comment: Listo compañero y gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

¿Por qué...?

```
 PreparedStatement getData = conexion.preparedStatement("SELECT IDUsuario, Nickname, Password, Email FROM usuario");
```

Cuándo...

```
  con = conexion.conecta();
```